# Error Running Program on Another Computer

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a piece of code that works perfectly on my computer. I emailed this code to a friend and whenever he runs it he gets a TypeError at this point
I have deleted the pySlot() decorator. I have tried classifying pySlot() decorator as QtCore.pylot(). None of them works. These are solutions posted on Stackoverflow. The code runs perfectly on my computer but generates the error message below when I run it on a friends computer-- I emailed the .py file (by attaching it to the email) to him

Error Message:

```
TypeError: connect() failed between clicked(bool) and on_generate_codes()
```

Why is this happening ?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os 

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox

class Ui_Dialog(object):

    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(531, 403)
        Dialog.setFixedSize(531,403)
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(Dialog)
        self.groupBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 251, 171))
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")



    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_generate_codes(self):

        """ 
        This method belongs to the generate button on the Dialog box
        When a user presses the button, a spreadsheet titled 

        """

    @pyqtSlot()   
    def reconcile(self):

        """
        This method reconciles 
        """

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Mywindow"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("Dialog", "Mar"))


if __name__ == "__main__"
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = UI_Dialog
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Following the answer by @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ below, the indentation for the two `@pyqtSlot()` decorators is only 3 spaces instead of the 4 you use above that

Comment: probably because I had to retype the code by hand. I have corrected the code submitted here to correct the indentation

Answer (score 0):

There might be some unreadable characters or extra spaces when he copies it from email.
I would suggest that you save it on a file and send the file instead of putting your codes inside an email.

Comment: I attached the .py to the email I sent him. He ran this code with spyder